# What is the type of the event.nativeEvent.submitter.name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, event-handling

I am trying to use the event.nativeEvent.submitter.name with typescript, but i cant find the correct type.

If someone can help me with this, i would be very glad.

Comment: Probably a `string`? What is `event`?

Comment: What is `submitter`?